# Portrait or Landscap for mobile and tablet

Tags: mobile-tools

Is it possible to somehow get landscape/Portrait detection when using module [mobile detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect). 
The issue thing is that I want to make different Panel Templates for Mobile; Landscape/portrait

I have found this php-code, see below, who gives the pixel of X and Y. With a compare of ($Y < $X) you can get the "Landscape" detection.

Is there anyone who knows any way to get this to work with panels everywhere and the theme; Adaptive Theme, so you can distinguish the views to different templates in Panels or Panels Everywhere?

```
 // everytime you want to find out the size of the screen, write the following 2 lines:
ncurses_wrefresh($fullscreen);
ncurses_getmaxyx ($fullscreen, $y, $x );
```

I think the future of design demands a possibility to make different design for especially mobile landscape/portrait. Google said on a conference year 2003 "that 65% of all *first visit* on a home-page are from a mobile devices" .

Premium solution is to optimize the interface by this facts, and there is a big difference between landscape/portrait when it comes to design and communications solutions.